# Ember router breaks on redirect to '/'

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-router

I'm having a hard time making my router understand that we are on a certain page and it should be displayed in the navigation as active. The situation is as follows:

```
 this.route('mainRoute', function() {
     this.route('list');
 });
```

The path we are interested in is /mainRoute. Unfortunately, there are a lot of legacy links that point to /mainRoute/list. The workaround for this was to redirect from the /mainRoute/list component back to the /mainRoute component.

```
beforeModel() {
   this.replaceWith('/mainRoute');
}
```

Now, my issue is that the /mainRoute navigation link will never be seen as active. I've tried adding a path for the /mainRoute ('/', '/mainRoute', 'mainRoute'), I've tried transforming it to a resource and a bunch of other things that passed my mind. But it either won't work, or will go in an infinite redirecting loop.

Any thoughts on it? Thanks so much, I really need a solution for this!

Comment: Why are you using `replaceWith()` and not `redirect`?

Comment: I don't know the reason, not my code

Comment: IMO using `current-when` or `pathRegex` seems like not addressing the root of your issue but just adding another fragile layer on top to hide the symptoms. I haven't used `replaceWith()` but with `redirect()` the redirected route should become active after a successful transition and the `<linkTo>` should reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *navigation links* are `{{link-to}}` components. There is a [current-when](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.14/classes/LinkComponent/properties/current-when?anchor=current-when) property you could use here. It accepts either a `boolean` or a `string`. The string is a space separated values with the route names you want this link to be active when.

**From the docs**

If you need a link to be 'active' even when it doesn't match the current route, you can use the
`current-when` argument.

```
<LinkTo @route='photoGallery' @current-when='photos'>
  Photo Gallery
</LinkTo>
```

```
{{#link-to 'photoGallery' current-when='photos'}}
  Photo Gallery
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this will certainly come in handy. Meanwhile I've found another solution using pathRegex:

`{{#link-to 'photoGallery' pathRegex='^photos'}}`